# Replicate part of data to different region

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying a use case with cosmoseDB where we want to maintain one CosmoseDB but split the data into US region and Europe region with some partition key?

And for inserting/updating documents, application know which region(US/Europe) the documents go so is it possible to point to the right region while inserting/updating the document?

Comment: Why don't you maintain a connection to each region and insert as needed? i.e. have two clients, one for each database

Answer (score 0):

As I know , Cosmos DB  global distribution mechanism guarantees consistency of all replica sets.

When you create the distribute cosmos db account, you enable the `geo-redundancy`.

[image]

You will see the regions of read and write separation.

[image]

Write operations are completed in write region and replicated to other read regions to ensure consistency. On the client side, there is no need to point to  specific region to write data. From perspective of consistency , all region data supposed to be same.

More details,  you could refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/distribute-data-globally#EnableGlobalDistribution).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Wouldn't all writes by this answer still end up in single region? I believe the focus of question is on having multiple write regions.

Answer (score 0):

**Can you have multiple write regions?**

DocumentDB has good build-in features to bring read operations closer to consumers by adding read-regions to your documentDB account. You can read about it in documentation: ["How to setup Azure Cosmos DB global distribution using the SQL API"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-global-distribution-sql-api).

My understanding based on this is that **there is always only 1 write region at any given time**. I would not bet my thumbs on it, but it's hinted at in documentation. For example in ["Connecting to a preferred region using the SQL API"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-global-distribution-sql-api#connecting-to-a-preferred-region-using-the-sql-api:):

> The SDK will automatically send all writes to the current write region.
>
> All reads will be sent to the first available region in the PreferredLocations list. If the request fails, the client will fail down the list to the next region, and so on.

***What you can do..***

Things get more complicated when you also want to distribute writes (espcially if you care about consistency and latency). DocumentDB's own documentation suggest you implement this as a combination of multiple accounts, each of which has its own local write region and automatic distribution to read/fallback node in other regions.

The downside is that your application would have to configure and implement reading from all accounts in your application code and merging the results. Having data well partitioned by geography could help avoid full fan-out at times but your DAL would still have to manage multiple storages internally.

This scenario is explained in more detail in documentation page
["Multi-master globally replicated database architectures with Azure Cosmos DB"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/multi-region-writers).

I would seriously consider if adding such complexity would be justified, or if distributing just the reads would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

All regions for a given account have the same replicated data. If you want to separate data across regions, you'd need to split it into two accounts.

Given partition A in the US and partition B in the EU – there is very little difference if A and B were under the same account, or under different accounts… the collection/db/account are all just logical wrappers on top of the partition.